# Word for "referring to common but not universal attributes of a group of people"?

Tags: vocabulary

I was recently out with friends and also with someone I didn't know too well. At some point during the night, I was imitating English spoken with a Mandarin speaker's accent for humorous effect, and the individual I didn't know went off on me, calling me *racist*.

Now,  I know perfectly well that finding humor in an accent or in grammatical mistakes is not in fact *racist.* That was never in question.

What is in question for me is whether there is in fact a word for this, making light of commonly true things about a group of people, like Australians saying *mate* or cat owners thinking their cat is really unique and unlike every other cat ever.

Is there a word aside from *stereotyping*? Which doesn't seem accurate to me, since it suggests I'm implying these things are true of all people in that group or even a majority, which isn't the case.

Comment: I think you mean "universal" rather than "ubiquitous".

Comment: Probably both work but universal is a better choice, I agree.

Comment: Traits? Not usually as nuanced as "stereotypes".

Comment: You can simply say the trait is ***characteristic***, and multiple such a traits are *characteristics*. They *characterize* such people. But of course, any given individual or sub-group may be *uncharacteristic* (*uncharacteristically tall*, e.g.).

Comment: There is a big difference between the question in the title ("word for referring to") and in the body ("word for... making light of"). Answers are coming in for both. Please could you make clear which you want?

Comment: Either and both are okay.

Comment: It's never adequate for a person to decide for themself that they haven't been racist, especially when some characteristic has been caricatured.

Answer (score 3):

[***to ape***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ape), according to The Oxford Dictionaries means:

> Imitate the behavior or manner of (someone or something), especially in an absurd or unthinking way

And from [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ape_2):

> ***ape somebody/something*** (especially North American English):
>   to copy the way somebody else behaves or talks, in order to make fun of them synonym mimic *We used to ape the teacher's southern accent.*

Answer (score 3):

It was a **[caricature](https://www.google.com/search?q=caricature%20definition)**

> noun
>   1. a picture, description, or imitation of a person in which certain striking characteristics are exaggerated in order to create a comic or
>   grotesque effect.
>  verb
>   1. make or give a caricature of.

based on a **[generalization](https://www.google.com/search?q=generalization%20definition)**

> noun
>   a general statement or concept obtained by inference from specific cases.

(Google)

I think it is safe and fair to say that any and every caricature of a race will be based on a generalization so the latter goes without saying.

Answer (score 1):

A term used to describe  linguistic and cultural differences is  ***[peculiarity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peculiarities)***, (
*distinctive feature*, *distinguishing characteristic*) :

> - a trait, manner, characteristic, or habit that is odd or unusual.
>     (The Free Dictionary)

- Linguistic and cultural peculiarities.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=linguistic%20peculiarities%2Ccultural%20peculiarities&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clinguistic%20peculiarities%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccultural%20peculiarities%3B%2Cc0): linguistic peculiarities, cultural peculiarities.

> - Through cross-cultural experiences, we become more broad-minded and tolerant of *cultural “peculiarities.*” When this is coupled with some formal study of the concept of culture, we not only gain new insights for improving our human relations, ...[Managing Cultural Differences](https://books.google.it/books?id=cWuLurrWvLQC&pg=PA21&dq=%22cultural%20peculiarities%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=CG6MVZLJJIn_UoDqgfgM&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22cultural%20peculiarities%22&f=false)
> - ... albeit of Gallo-Romance origin, is nonetheless not a dialect of Provencal. It is Ibero-Romance by virtue of its geographic position, but cannot, because of its history and *linguistic peculiarities*, be counted among Ibero-Romance languages. [Cultural and Linguistic Factors in Word Formation:](https://books.google.it/books?id=UVX0kkpx6h4C&pg=PA196&dq=%22linguistic%20peculiarities%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=oW6MVeDhBovvUtezgOgH&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22linguistic%20peculiarities%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

**Clique:** a group of people with shared interests or other features in common and do not readily allow others to join them

**Coterie:** a small group of people with shared interests or tastes, especially one that is exclusive of other people

Source: NOAD

Answer (score 0):

**cultural quirks**

*cultural*: relating to the ideas, customs and social behaviour of a society

*quirk*: a peculiar aspect of a person's character or behaviour

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Examples showing how 'cultural quirks' is used in the literature:

['Befuddling citizenship requirements expose cultural quirks', WSJ Blog, 16 Feb 2015](http://blogs.wsj.com/expat/2015/02/16/befuddling-citizenship-requirements-expose-cultural-quirks/)

['An uncommon history of common courtesy: customs, quirks and social snafus around the world': NGS, 2011](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Uncommon-History-Common-Courtesy-Customs/dp/1426208138/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1435273011&sr=8-6&keywords=Cultural%20quirks)

*Please note that I have answered your question as expressed in the title.*

Answer (score 0):

Let’s just say that you were, without malicious intent, “**lampooning**” the stereotypical characteristics of a social group.

> [**lampoon**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=lampoon+&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=lampoon+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.5.4481641...........0.SHQnDLM1Lig&gws_rd=ssl) *verb*: 3rd person present: lampoons; past tense: lampooned; past participle: lampooned; gerund or present participle: **lampooning**
>
> **1**. publicly criticize (someone or something) by using ridicule, irony, or sarcasm.
>
> • "the senator made himself famous as a pinch-penny watchdog of public spending, *lampooning* dubious federal projects"
>
> *synonyms*: satirize, mock, ridicule, make fun of, caricature, burlesque, parody, tease

(Google)

Answer (score 0):

The word you seek is “metanym”
Naming a group for a common characteristic, like calling hippies “longhairs” or business people “suits.”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).